# React Native - Branch link in an Intercom message opens browser first instead of the app

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links, intercom

I'm finding it hard to get Branch.io deeplinking to work with Intercom.

The Branch link works well when opened via native Messages app - opens the app directly when tapped.

But if we send this link through an Intercom message, and then tap on it on the phone, the result is not as expected:

---

### On iOS

- Open Intercom messages view.
- Tap on the Branch link (sent from Intercom console).
- Browser opens with an alert asking to open the native app ('Open this page in "MyApp"?').
- Press "Open".
- App detects the Branch parameters on the link and redirects to the correct page.

***Expected Behavior***

App should detect the link directly without being handed over by browser.

---

### On Android

- Open Intercom messages view.
- Tap on the Branch link (sent from Intercom console).
- List of suggested apps pops up - including "MyApp".
- Tap on "MyApp".
- App detects the Branch link ONLY, but without the parameters - which then will not redirect to any page.

  - Now send the app to the background (eg: Tap on home button), and then open "MyApp" again.
  - Branch will now detect the link with the parameters and redirect to the correct page *(this sometimes happens in iOS as well)*.

***Expected Behavior***

Branch should detect the link **with parameters** directly, without the need to send the app to background and reopen.

---

Does anyone have an idea what I have missed out on? or a workaround?

I was thinking to setup Universal Links by uploading the Association File.. ‍♂️

Btw, Branch.io configurations are all done and works perfectly with other social media apps.

```
react-native: 0.61.5
react-native-branch: 5.0.0-beta.1
react-native-intercom: 16.0.0
```

Comment: Can you share a sample link and video recording of the behavior?

Comment: Hey @KartikShandilya. Unfortunately I am unable to share a video recording due to sensitive content :(
I'll also update the question with an error thrown by branch when opening normal links on Android (detected as Universal/App link).

Comment: Can you mail us at support@branch.io so that we can resolve it for you?